# Get radio button data from mysql in input form

Tags: php

I've already searched and I don't understand why this isn't working.

```
    <input type="radio" name="soort" value="in"  echo ('.$_GET['soort'].'=="in")?"checked":"">In-Company<br />
    <input type="radio" name="soort" value="open" echo ('.$_GET['soort'] . '"=="open")?"checked":">Open inschrijving<br />
```

This isn't working either:

```
    <input type="radio" name="soort" value="in"  echo ($soort=="in")?"checked":"">In-Company<br />
    <input type="radio" name="soort" value="open" echo ($soort=="open")?"checked":">Open inschrijving<br />
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong or I'm missing something.

If anyone could help me out here or put me in the right direction. Thank you!!!!

This is the entire form.

```
 print '<form action="edit_dienst.php" method="post">
    <p><strong>Titel</strong> <textarea name="navigatie" columns="20" rows="5">' . $row['navigatie'] . '</textarea></p>         
    <p><strong>Tekst</strong> <textarea name="tekst" columns="20" rows="5">' . $row['tekst'] . '</textarea></p>
    <input type="radio" name="soort" value="in"  echo ($soort=="in")?"checked":"">In-Company<br />
    <input type="radio" name="soort" value="open" echo ($soort=="open")?"checked":">Open inschrijving<br />
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pas aan!" />
    </form><p></p>';
```

Comment: u have missed `<?php` open tag.. see my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $soort=$_GET['soort']; ?>
<input type="radio" name="soort" value="in"  <?php echo ($soort=="in")?"checked":"" ?>>In-Company<br />
<input type="radio" name="soort" value="open" <?php echo ($soort=="open")?"checked":"" ?>>Open inschrijving<br />
```

Comment: Thanks!
I still can't get it to work though. Your code must be right, so it's probably me. I will look at some beginning tutorials first and maybe after that I could solve the problems with my form.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

since i see 'print', i infer that you are already in the php tag. you can the below script.

```
$soortInChecked = ($soort=="in")?"checked":"";
$soortOpenChecked = ($soort=="open")?"checked":"";

print '<form action="edit_dienst.php" method="post">
    <p><strong>Titel</strong> <textarea name="navigatie" columns="20" rows="5">' . $row['navigatie'] . '</textarea></p>
    <p><strong>Tekst</strong> <textarea name="tekst" columns="20" rows="5">' . $row['tekst'] . '</textarea></p>
    <input type="radio" name="soort" value="in" '.$soortInChecked.' >In-Company<br />
    <input type="radio" name="soort" value="open" '.$soortOpenChecked.' >Open inschrijving<br />
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pas aan!" />
    </form><p></p>';
```

the issue is that you have given the echo inside the quotes. check the tutorials for print/echo also the difference in single and double quotes in php to start with.